# Service not starting when called from MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I have written a Service that listens for UDP messages then changes a TextView and an ImageView based on the parsed message from the UDP messages. I'm getting an NPE when attemping to use a public `getParsedMessage` method from the service, which means that the service has not been started. It is declared as a service in the manifest exactly as it is spelled, so I know that is not the problem. Here is my MainActivity's code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AlertAssignments mAlertAssignments;



Button startListeningButton;

boolean started;
int counter;
boolean mBound = false;
Context context;
ListenerService mListenerService;

TextView mTextView;
TextView mBlinkView;
ImageView mImageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alert_text);
    mBlinkView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blinking_text);
    Animation mAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(50);
    mAnimation.setStartOffset(20);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mBlinkView.startAnimation(mAnimation); //animation value
    mAlertAssignments = new AlertAssignments();

    Integer parsedMessage = Integer.valueOf(mListenerService.getParsedMessage()); //this is the cause of the NPE

    mImageView.setImageResource(mAlertAssignments.alarmImages[parsedMessage]);

    if(parsedMessage >= 10 && parsedMessage <= 19 && parsedMessage != 0) {
        mTextView.setText(mAlertAssignments.alertTextMessages[parsedMessage]);
    } else {
        mBlinkView.setText(mAlertAssignments.alertTextMessages[parsedMessage]);
    }

}
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        ListenerService.LocalBinder binder = (ListenerService.LocalBinder) service;
        mListenerService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //start listener service
    Intent listenerServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListenerService.class);
    this.bindService(listenerServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //unbind from service
    if(mBound) {
        this.unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }

}
```

}

The error occurs on line 75, which is marked above (`Integer parsedMessage = Integer.valueOf(mListenerService.getParsedMessage());`). I have followed the developer.android documentation in setting up and starting my service, however i seem to see conflicting information in multiple locations. Here is my ListenerService:

```
public class ListenerService extends Service{
public String the_alarm_S;
public String parsedMessage = "";
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    ListenerService getService() {
        return ListenerService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}



static String UDP_BROADCAST = "UDPBroadcast";

//Boolean shouldListenForUDPBroadcast = false;
DatagramSocket socket;

private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(InetAddress broadcastIP, Integer port) throws Exception {
    byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
    if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port, broadcastIP);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    }
    //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
    Log.e("UDP", "Waiting for UDP broadcast");
    socket.receive(packet);

    String senderIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();

    Log.e("UDP", "Got UDB broadcast from " + senderIP + ", message: " + message);


    broadcastIntent(senderIP, message);
    setParsedMessage(message);
    socket.close();

}

private void broadcastIntent(String senderIP, String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListenerService.UDP_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra("sender", senderIP);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    Log.e("UDP", "Message received containing" +message);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
    UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress broadcastIP = InetAddress.getByName("172.16.238.255"); //172.16.238.42 //192.168.1.255
                Integer port = 12001;
                while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                    listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(broadcastIP, port);
                }
                //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    UDPBroadcastThread.start();
}

private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;

private void setParsedMessage(String messageContents) {
    the_alarm_S = messageContents;
    String parseMessage[] = the_alarm_S.split("!!!");
    Log.e("UDP", "Parsed message with value " + parseMessage[1]);
    parsedMessage = parseMessage[1];

}
public String getParsedMessage() {
    return parsedMessage;
}

void stopListen() {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
    socket.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopListen();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
    startListenForUDPBroadcast();
    Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
    return START_STICKY;
}




}
```

I had previously been using an AsyncTask to fetch this data, however, I need it to be constantly fetching the data and updating the `TextView` and `ImageView` objects, and due to the ping speed using a `while` loop to do this caused it to run out of memory due to i assume it running on the UI thread. AlertAssignments is simply an Enum that binds image files and Strings to ordinal array values so that I can easily change the `TextView` and `ImageView` based on the integer value of the parsed message (`parsedMessage[1]` of the original message `xxx!!!n!!!xxx` gives `parsedMessage[1] = n`)

Any advice on how to resolve what is probably an oversight on my part would be great, thanks

Comment: Call `mListenerService.getParsedMessage()` method inside `onServiceConnected` probably using  `mListenerService` before service start or add a check `mBound` is true before accessing method

Comment: I set `mListenerService.getParsedMessage()` to a global string and changed the variable on line 75 to match based on your recommendation, still get the same NPE in the same point

Comment: also added a check to perform this operation if `mBound = true` with a log output if false and I see in logcat that it is not bound, which means for some reason the service is not binding when I attempt to bind

Comment: have you declared your service in manifest.xml

Comment: yes, as mentioned in the first paragraph of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Android activity lifecycle:

[image]

One thing you'll notice is that `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`. This means you're trying to access the service *before* it actually starts.

The way I would work around this is to start your service in `onCreate()` (so it will start as soon as your activity is first created) and then read the value inside `onResume()`, so that every time your activity comes back into the foreground it will update according to the service.

You may also notice that if resources are required, your app could be killed as early as `onPause()`. It would be a good idea to do your cleanup there, instead of `onDestroy()`.

**EDIT:**

If the above option didn't work, I suspect there's a race condition going on. Just because you started the service before you read from it, doesn't mean it was fully configured. Thankfully, you have a listener to tell you when the service is bound.

You can write a separate method specifically for updating the UI, and have your activity only call it once the service has started:

```
public class MyActivity {

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            ListenerService.LocalBinder binder = (ListenerService.LocalBinder) service;
            mListenerService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;

            readFromService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    private void readFromService() {
        Integer parsedMessage = Integer.valueOf(mListenerService.getParsedMessage()); //this is the cause of the NPE

        mImageView.setImageResource(mAlertAssignments.alarmImages[parsedMessage]);

        if(parsedMessage >= 10 && parsedMessage <= 19 && parsedMessage != 0) {
            mTextView.setText(mAlertAssignments.alertTextMessages[parsedMessage]);
        } else {
            mBlinkView.setText(mAlertAssignments.alertTextMessages[parsedMessage]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, moving `this.bindService(listenerServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` et al from `onStart()` to `onCreate` still gives the same issue of non-binding. I also noticed that while it is compiling thanks to the if statement not attempting to call the method from the service, soon after compile the Service appears to die with an NPE on the `DatagramSocket.close()` call in the ListenerService code, so at least we know the service is starting, just not binding

Comment: @Tadhg Sounds like it might be a potential race condition if you're now seeing the service start but not bind. See my edit for another idea.